# why do we use the "plain" argument in server.hasarg("plain") in the ESP8266WebServer library

Tags: http, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I am writing an Arduino code to retrieve a JSON code from the ESP8266 webserver, i used postman to send the POST request and included the JSON code in the body of the request. The Arduino code is supposed to handle the response to the client(postman in this case) but i am unable to run the code unless the "server.hasarg()" method contains the argument "plain". Even though i never included such an argument in the URL.
Keep in mind that "server" in this case is an object of the ESP8266WebServer class.

I tried running the code while leaving the server.hasarg() method  as an empty string.

Comment: It is the way in the ESP8266WebServer library to get the body of the request. If the content-type is url encoded, then the parameters and their values are parsed. For other content-types the parameters from url are parsed and the body of the request is available as a 'fake' parameter named "plain".